# Comparing two integers without using any comparison (recursion, python)

Tags: python, recursion

How would i go about comparing two integers without using ( < and > ), it´s allowed to use +, -, ==

My first idea was to this.

Since they are integers and you can use addition, you can increment one until one number is equal to the other.  Let's say you're comparing 4 and 7 to see the relationship.

```
N   M   N'  M'
4 | 7
4 | 7 | 5 | 8
4 | 7 | 6 | 9
4 | 7 | 7 | 10
```

Each row increments N' and M' by one (+1) from the last iteration.

You can see that on the last row, N' == M, i.e. the incremented N equals the original M.   Thus, we have discovered that N < M (as N can be incremented to become M).

If the inputs we reversed (7,4 instead of 4,7), we would find that eventually M' == N, which would tell us that N > M.

This is what i have so far, but it doesnt work

```
def less_than(a, b):  # ONLY NEEDS TO WORK FOR POSITIVE INTEGERS
    if a == b:
        return False
    a2 = a + 1
    b2 = b + 1
    if a2 == b:
        return True
    elif b2 == a:
        return False
    else:
        return less_than(a, b)
```

Comment: Well, `a2` and `b2` will be the same in every time you call `less_than(a, b)`. If you really want to solve your problem recursively, you have to add another parameter to your function signature that tells you the recursion depth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your function needs to work only for positive integers, you can decrement both numbers at the same time and see which one of them reaches `0` first. Then you can easily decide:

```
def less_than(a, b):  # ONLY NEEDS TO WORK FOR POSITIVE INTEGERS
    if a == b:
        return False
    while a != 0 and b != 0:
        a -= 1
        b -= 1
    # we're out of the loop, one of the numbers should be 0
    if a == 0:
        return True
    return False

>>> less_than(4, 5)
True
>>> less_than(4, 4)
False
>>> less_than(4, 3)
False
```